# Is possible to sort a view in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-mango

I'm new in CouchDB and I'm wondering if is possible and how is possible to sort a view in CouchDB.

PS: I'm using CouchDB 3.0.0

Comment: Yes. Take advantage of [view collation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/collation.html). Otherwise you'll have to post process for sort.  Also read over the [pagination recipe](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/pagination.html) for inspiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to sort views. In fact, all views are always sorted. It's impossible to *not* sort a view.

Each view is sorted according to the [collation rules](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/collation.html) for the key `emit`ted from the map function.